# Java programming arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a tic tac toe board (7x7) using arrays. 
The board must look exactly like this:

```
+-+-+-+  
| | | |  
+-+-+-+  
| | | |   
+-+-+-+   
| | | |   
+-+-+-+
```

What I have:

```
import java.util.Arrays; 

String[][] board = new String [7][7];
    int rows = 7;
    int columns = 1;
    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
            System.out.print("+-+-+-+");    
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to fit the arrays in and when I print a multidimensional array with "Arrays.toString" I recieve the reference.

Comment: This is a statement -- where is the question? It seems odd to put the drawing characters in the array -- it would be more usual when representing a board to store only the pieces within the board in the array, and form the drawing characters from the logic that renders it.

Comment: Neg voted. Because there's no attempt to do any looping. This is a very basic question, which clearly states that the board is (7x7), which means...something needs to loop 7 times. Here's a rough solution. 1. A for loop which loops 7 times. 2. Modulus of each iteration of the loop count against the value of '2' to alternate the string you push into the array element, 3. printf() to sort out your alignment issues

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String[] board = {"+-+-+-+"};
    String[] board2 = {"| | | |"};
    for(int x=0;x<4;x++)
    {
        System.out.println(board[0]);
        if(x==3)
        break;
        System.out.println(board2[0]);
    }
```

Try to figure out what this code is doing, and if you have any questions feel free to comment and ask me.

Comment: I ran this on Ideone.com because I don't currently have a java compiler on my computer. The spacing seems to be fine there.

Comment: Thanks for answering, why do you use 4 in the for loop and why do you break at 3?

Comment: I use 4 in the loop because for a 7x7 board, you are printing "+-+-+-+" 4 times, and are printing "| | | |" 3 times. If I were to remove the break at x=3 (Which is the fourth time the loop is running since the loop starts at 0, and goes like this 0,1,2,3) then the program would also print "| | | |" 4 times, however what I do is that after it has printed "+-+-+-+" 4 times, that means up to that it has printed "| | | |" 3 times, and since we don't want to print "| | | |" any more times, we break and exit the loop.

Comment: If you think this is the best answer, you can accept it as that by clicking on the arrow under the rating for answers

Comment: OK, so technically you ARE using arrays.  But you're using them as scalars, which is kind of pointless.  And `break` directly underneath `if` with no indentation and no braces?  Seriously?

Answer (score 1):

Asking homework and final exam questions on Stack Overflow? - it's that time of year. I remember a professor made me print a diamond pattern using asterisks... I tried selling each diamond pattern for $5. I didn't sell any. No businesses needed that skill and they said their developers could beat my price by a wide margin.

Well, it looks like you can achieve this using two different arrays, a couple for loops, a modulus operator, and a print function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] a = { "+", "-", "+", "-", "+", "-", "+" }; //horizontal bars
    String[] b = { "|", " ", "|", " ", "|", " ", "|" }; //vertical bars

    //both arrays are the same size, so either length will do, or just set the i < 7 in the second loop parameter
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        //i % 2 = the remainder of i divided by 2, example: 1/2 = 0 with remainder 1, so 1 % 2 = 1
        //you will see this again if you ever try to alternate colors in a programmatically generated table row for example
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            print(a);
        } else {
            print(b);
        }
    }
}
static void print(String[] array) {
    //for all but the last in the array, print inline
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
    //for the last array index, append a newline
    System.out.println(array[array.length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: plus uno for the intro... you should've gone public with it, Nasdaq listed